# Setting cookies across secure and non-secure environments?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I am working on a site where both http and https versions resolve. The problem is, people often arrive at the non-secure version through old links, but then if they return through a Google search get sent to the secure version which ignores the previously set cookies. The long-term solution is to only serve up the https version, but this may take a while before they implement. As a faster solution, is there any way to set a cookie in a non-secure environment so it persists if the user goes to the secure version of the same domain?

Comment: Can't you just add redirect code to the https version?

Comment: Yes, and this will happen eventually but it's release dependent. I can push updates to the JS that sets the cookie through a tag management system (Google Tag Manager) immediately

Comment: So: until the server admins add the couple of lines to the config to redirect.... `if (window.location.href.indexOf("http://")===0) window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/^http:/, "https:");`